# How to find indexes of nested array elements based on id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, multidimensional-array

So I have a nested array of objects that has the following structure:

```
let pages = [
  [
    {
      leftCol: [
        { height: 34, id: 10 },
        { height: 18, id: 20 },
        { height: 45, id: 30 },
        { height: 59, id: 40 },
      ],
    },
    {
      rightCol: [
        { height: 34, id: 50 },
        { height: 34, id: 60 },
        { height: 34, id: 70 },
      ],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      leftCol: [
        { height: 34, id: 80 },
        { height: 18, id: 90 },
        { height: 45, id: 100 },
        { height: 59, id: 110 },
      ],
    },
    {
      rightCol: [
        { height: 34, id: 120 },
        { height: 34, id: 130 },
        { height: 34, id: 140 },
      ],
    },
  ],
];
```

Now I would like to create a method that can return the index of an element based on a `id` given as a parameter aswell as return the index of the outer element. For example:

`findIdx(pages, 30)` would return  the idx of the element (2) aswell as the idx of the outer array (0).

`findIdx(pages, 110)` would return  the idx of the element (3) aswell as the idx of the outer array (1).

The best I could come up with is the following method:

```
function getIdxAndPageNumOfColumn(array, columnIdx, payloadId) {
  let idx;
  let pageNum;

  for (pageNum = 0; pageNum < array.length; pageNum++) {
    let leftCol = array[pageNum][0].leftCol;
    let rightCol = array[pageNum][1].rightCol;
    let column = columnIdx === 0 ? leftCol : rightCol;
    idx = column.findIndex(item => item.id == payloadId);
    if (idx > -1) break;
  }

  return {
    idx: idx,
    pageNum: pageNum,
  };
}
```

But this requires me to specify a `columnIdx` as a parameter (a `columnIdx` of 0 will always be equal to the `leftCol` in the pages array, and `columnIdx` of 1 would be equal to `rightCol`). For some reason I can't get this to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not get three indices because of three nested arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reducer makes for a fairly concise and readable solution, though in the example below it requires the structure to remain static as it references `leftCol` and `rightCol` specifically. You could make it more general by replacing the desctructuring with an `Object.entries()` loop.

**Directly destructuring the page object**

```js
let pages = [ [ { leftCol: [ { height: 34, id: 10 }, { height: 18, id: 20 }, { height: 45, id: 30 }, { height: 59, id: 40 }, ], }, { rightCol: [ { height: 34, id: 50 }, { height: 34, id: 60 }, { height: 34, id: 70 }, ], }, ], [ { leftCol: [ { height: 34, id: 80 }, { height: 18, id: 90 }, { height: 45, id: 100 }, { height: 59, id: 110 }, ], }, { rightCol: [ { height: 34, id: 120 }, { height: 34, id: 130 }, { height: 34, id: 140 }, ], }, ],];

function getIdxAndPageNumOfColumn(array, payloadId) {

  const pageAndIndex = array.reduce((acc, [{leftCol}, {rightCol}], i) =>  {
    if ((leftMatch = leftCol.findIndex(p => p.id === payloadId)) !== -1) {
      acc['idx'] = leftMatch;
      acc['pageNum'] = i;
      acc['colIdx'] = 0;
    } else if ((rightMatch = rightCol.findIndex(p => p.id === payloadId)) !== -1) {
      acc[idx] = rightMatch;
      acc['pageNum'] = i;
      acc['colIdx'] = 1;
    }
    return acc
  },{})
  
  return pageAndIndex;
}

console.log(getIdxAndPageNumOfColumn(pages, 30));
console.log(getIdxAndPageNumOfColumn(pages, 110));
```

---

**Using Object.values**

```js
let pages = [[{ leftCol: [{ height: 34, id: 10 }, { height: 18, id: 20 }, { height: 45, id: 30 }, { height: 59, id: 40 },], }, { rightCol: [{ height: 34, id: 50 }, { height: 34, id: 60 }, { height: 34, id: 70 },], },], [{ leftCol: [{ height: 34, id: 80 }, { height: 18, id: 90 }, { height: 45, id: 100 }, { height: 59, id: 110 },], }, { rightCol: [{ height: 34, id: 120 }, { height: 34, id: 130 }, { height: 34, id: 140 },], },],];

function getIdxAndPageNumOfColumn(array, payloadId) {

  const pageAndIndex = array.reduce((acc, pArr, pi) => {
    pArr.forEach((col, ci) => {
      Object.values(col).forEach(v => {
        if ((match = v.findIndex(p => p.id === payloadId)) !== -1) {
          acc['idx'] = match;
          acc['pageNum'] = pi;
          acc['colIdx'] = ci;
        }
      });
    });
    return acc
  }, {});
  
  return pageAndIndex;
}

console.log(getIdxAndPageNumOfColumn(pages, 30));
console.log(getIdxAndPageNumOfColumn(pages, 110));
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried all the methods and yours seems to be working the best with the best results. Can't believe how much I struggled hehe. Cheers :).

Answer (score 2):

You could take a dynamic approach for getting all indices of the wanted object.

```js
function findIdx(array, id) {
    function find(array) {
        if (!array) return;
        let inner,
            index = array.findIndex(o => {
                if (o.id === id) return true;
                if (Array.isArray(o)) return inner = find(o);
                return inner = find(o.leftCol || o.rightCol);
            });
        return index !== -1 && [index, ...(inner || [])];
    }

    return find(array);
}

let pages = [[{ leftCol: [{ height: 34, id: 10 }, { height: 18, id: 20 }, { height: 45, id: 30 }, { height: 59, id: 40 }] }, { rightCol: [{ height: 34, id: 50 }, { height: 34, id: 60 }, { height: 34, id: 70 }] }], [{ leftCol: [{ height: 34, id: 80 }, { height: 18, id: 90 }, { height: 45, id: 100 },{ height: 59, id: 110 }] }, { rightCol: [{ height: 34, id: 120 }, { height: 34, id: 130 }, { height: 34, id: 140 }] }]];

console.log(findIdx(pages, 30));  // [0, 0, 2]
console.log(findIdx(pages, 110)); // [1, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
const findPage = (pages, pageid) =>
  new Promise((res) => {
    pages.map((page) => {
      page.map((p) => {
        Object.entries(p).map(([k, v]) => {
          const x = v.filter((_) => _.id === pageid);
          if (x.length > 0) {
            res(x["0"]);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });

findPage(pages, idWhichYouSearch).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
function findIdx(pages, id) {
    for (let index = 0; index < pages.length; index++) {
        const cols = pages[index];
        for (const e of cols) {
            for (const key in e) {
                const item = e[key].find((a) => a.id == id);
                if (item) return index;
            }
        }
    }
}

const item = findIdx(pages, 110);
console.log(item);
```